# How to save Foreign Key text input in Django model form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

My view passes an id to my form. This id is a foreign key from another table. I am not able to save the id in the database table.
(id : voucher_id,  table in which i am saving the form : TmpPlInvoicedet)

**What i want to do**

**Send voucher_id from (View) to ---> TmpFormDetForm (Form) ---> TmpPlInvoicedet (DB)**

Trying to get instance from the table 'TmpPlInvoice' (which has voucher_id as PK) and save it in the form gives me

**DoesNotExist at /new/ TmpPlInvoice matching query does not exist**

What am i doing wrong?

**Views.py**

```
def new_invoic(request):

    # Create a voucher id according to my criteria
    temp_vid = TmpPlInvoice.objects.order_by().values_list("voucher_id", flat=True).distinct()
    if not temp_vid:
          voucher_id = str(1).zfill(4)
    else:
          voucher_id = str(int(max(temp_vid)) + 1).zfill(4)

    # POST METHOD TRying to show the voucher_id in the form in readonly format
    if request.method == 'POST':
          form_pk = TmpForm(request.POST or None, voucher_id=voucher_id,initial={'voucher_id': voucher_id})

          if form.is_valid():
               form_pk.save()
               form = TmpFormDetForm(request.POST or None, voucher=voucher_id, initial={'voucher': voucher_id})
               # My assumption is that since i have save the voucher_id in the TmpInvoice table so i can get the PK voucher_id value and save it in the TmpInvoiceDetForm
               form.save()
               return HttpResponseRedirect('/new/')
          else:
               return render_to_response('test.html',{'form': form, 'form_pk': form_pk},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
          form_pk = TmpForm(voucher_id=voucher_id,initial={'voucher_id': voucher_id})
          form = TmpFormDetForm(voucher=voucher_id, initial={'voucher': voucher_id})
          return render_to_response('test.html',{'form': form, 'form_pk': form_pk},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**Forms.py**

```
# This form contains the FK. This one is giving errors while saving.

class TmpFormDetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         voucher = kwargs.pop('voucher', None)
         super(TmpFormDetForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         self.fields['voucher'].initial = TmpPlInvoice.objects.get(voucher_id=voucher)

    voucher = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'40'}))

    class Meta:
          model = TmpPlInvoicedet
          exclude = ['emp_id','particulars','qty', 'rate' , 'itemtot', 'stock_code' ]
          widgets = {
              'voucher': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': '', 'required': 'False', 'name': 'voucher','readonly': 'readonly'}),
               'lineitem': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Add Total', 'required': 'False',  'blank': 'True'})}

# This form takes the PK. I save the PK here first.
class TmpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         voucher_id = kwargs.pop('voucher_id', None)
         super(TmpFor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         self.fields['voucher_id'].initial = voucher_id

    pos_code = MyModelChoiceField(queryset=Positions.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'select2_single form-control', 'blank': 'True'}))
    cust = MyModelChoiceField(queryset=Custodian.objects.all(), to_field_name='acct_id',widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'select2_single form-control', 'blank': 'True'}))
    acct = MyModelChoiceField(queryset=Item.objects.all(), to_field_name='stock_code',widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'select2_single form-control', 'blank': 'True'}))

    voucher_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'tabindex': '-1', 'class': 'form-control has-feedback-left', 'id': 'single_cal1','aria-describedby': 'inputSuccess2Status'}))

class Meta:
    model = TmpPlInvoice
    exclude = ['net_amt', 'post_date', 'address', 'posted']
    widgets = {
                'voucher_id': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': '', 'required':'False', 'name': 'voucher_id', 'readonly': 'readonly'}),
                'voucher_date': forms.TextInput(attrs={'tabindex': '-1', 'class': 'form-control has-feedback-left', 'id': 'single_cal1','aria-describedby': 'inputSuccess2Status'}),
                'particulars': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Add Particulars', 'required':'False'}),
            }
```

**Models.py**

```
class TmpPlInvoicedet(models.Model):
     stock_code = models.CharField(max_length=13, blank=True, null=True)
     voucher = models.ForeignKey(TmpPlInvoice, db_column='voucher_id')
     lineitem = models.CharField(max_length=6)
     particulars = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
     qty = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
     rate = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
     itemtot = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
     emp_id = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
     managed = False
     db_table = 'tmp_pl_invoicedet'
     unique_together = (('voucher', 'lineitem'),)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy peesy.

```
def master_detail(request):
    def get_new_voucher_id():
       temp_vid = TmpPlInvoice.objects.order_by().values_list("voucher_id", flat=True).distinct()
       logger.info('Voucher ID already present %s', temp_vid)
       if not temp_vid:
           voucher_id = str(1).zfill(4)
       else:
           voucher_id = str(int(max(temp_vid)) + 1).zfill(4)
       return voucher_id

  voucher_id = get_new_voucher_id()
  author_form = TmpForm(initial={'voucher_id': voucher_id})
  author = TmpPlInvoice()
  BookFormSet = inlineformset_factory(TmpPlInvoice, TmpPlInvoicedet, exclude=('emp_id', 'itemtot', 'voucher', 'lineitem','id'),
                                    form=TmpFormDetForm, extra=1)
  formset = BookFormSet(instance=author)

  if request.method == 'POST':
       logger.info('*'*50)
       author = TmpForm(request.POST, initial={'voucher_id': voucher_id})
       if author.is_valid():
           logger.info('Data for Author is %s', author.cleaned_data)
           created_author = author.save()
           formset = BookFormSet(request.POST, instance=created_author)

           if formset.is_valid():
               logger.info('Data for Book is %s', formset.cleaned_data)
               formset.save()
           else:
                logger.info('Formset errors %s', formset.errors)
       else:
           logger.info('Master form  errors %s', author.errors)
           logger.info('*'*50)
       return HttpResponseRedirect('/new/')
  else:
       logger.info('Formset from GET is %s', formset.errors)
       return render_to_response('new_invoice.html',
                              {'form': author_form, 'formset': formset},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be creating a new invoice ID and then, in your form, attempting to get the invoice matching that ID. But that invoice doesn't exist yet, of course, because you haven't created it.

You might want to use `get_or_create` to ensure that the invoice is created if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Great observation!. In the same view, i am passing the ID to another form and saving the ID to the table 'TmpPlInvoice'. I did not add it to avoid over complication. Stupidity on my behalf. Let me edit this.